# Does Boost::Geometry support Manhattant data?

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

I have been using boost::geometry::simplify before and very satisfy with the result but now I have input as Manhattan data and want output is Manhattan data also. I tried to look around on their website but it seems boost::geometry does not support fot Manhattan data only.

Unable to find documents from boost geometry